# python merge interaction data into one row

Tags: python, loops, merge

I have a .csv dataset with rfid data about at which second people had an interaction:

tag_me is the variable of person 1, tag_them is the name of the person you have met at that second, time_local_s is the time at which the interaction took place. The rfid's started recording at 19:00:00 so the first interaction was recorded at 19:22:36 (19:00:00 + 1356 seconds).

```
tag_me,tag_them,time_local_s
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1356
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1360
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1361
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1362
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1363
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1364
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1366
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1366
0x597E5627,0x36570942,1366
0x597E5627,0x3C3A21AD,1369
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1370
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1372
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1372
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1374
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1374
0x597E5627,0x064F5882,1379
```

I would like to group each interaction to one line, recording the time when the interaction started, ended and how long it took. therefore i can filter on a certain threshold (two rfid's seeing each other for 2 seconds is ofcourse not really an interaction.

```
tag_me,tag_them,time_start,time_end,total_time
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1356,1363,7
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1364,1363,1
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365,1366,1
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1366,1366,1
0x597E5627,0x36570942,1366,1366,1
0x597E5627,0x3C3A21AD,1369,1369.1
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1370,1374,4
0x597E5627,0x064F5882,1379,1379,1
```

I tried this so far:

```
data = []
with open('timemerger.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        data.append(line)

past_interactions = []
interactions = []
now = -1
new_data = []
for line in enumerate(data):
    if line["time_local_s"] > now:
        for tag_them, indices in past_interactions:
            if tag_them not in data:
                interactions.append(entry["tag_them"])
```

---------------EDIT 7-5-2018----------

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filter20seconden1.csv')

cols = df.columns.difference(['time_start', 'time_end'])
grps = df.time_start.sub(df.time_end.shift()).gt(20).cumsum()
gpby = df.groupby(grps)
new = gpby.agg(dict(time_start='min', 
      time_end='max')).join(gpby[cols].sum())
```

Comment: You should probably be looking into `pandas` for this kind of task

Comment: @sacul yeah i tried searching some pandas methods but had no succes, i indeed think pandas is the way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you mentioned in your comments you don't mind using `pandas`, here is one solution. It's a bit long, there is probably a more efficient way, but I think it works:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in your csv
df = pd.read_csv('timemerger.csv')
# Create a new column with an "interaction number"
df = df.assign(interaction_num=(df.tag_them != df.tag_them.shift()).cumsum())
# Groupby the interaction number, and extract the min and max times:
gb = (df.groupby('interaction_num')
      .apply(
          lambda x: pd.Series([x['time_local_s'].min(),
                               x['time_local_s'].max()]
          ))
      .rename(columns={0:'time_start', 1:'time_end'}))
# Merge the min and max times per interaction number with your original dataframe:
df = df.merge(gb, left_on = 'interaction_num', right_index=True)
# Create a new column for length of time, groupby interaction again, and take first value:
df = (df.assign(total_time = df.time_end - df.time_start)
      .groupby('interaction_num')
      .first()
      .drop('time_local_s', axis=1))
# Finally, save your dataframe:
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=None)
```

Your new `output.csv` will look like this:

```
tag_me,tag_them,time_start,time_end,total_time
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1356,1363,7
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1364,1364,0
0x597E5627,0x3C992634,1365,1366,1
0x597E5627,0x7DA8FFB0,1366,1366,0
0x597E5627,0x36570942,1366,1366,0
0x597E5627,0x3C3A21AD,1369,1369,0
0x597E5627,0x06497CA4,1370,1374,4
0x597E5627,0x064F5882,1379,1379,0
```

Note that there are zeros when an interaction started and ended on the same second, whereas your desired outcome had `1`. This is easy to change by using `df.replace({'total_time':{0:1}}, inplace=True)` before your `to_csv` (I kept it there because I think otherwise your data is losing the difference between zero second interactions vs. 1 second interactions).

**Breakdown**:

The first [`assign()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`.shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) creates a column for separate interactions:

```
       tag_me    tag_them  time_local_s  interaction_num
...
3  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1362                1
4  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1363                1
5  0x597E5627  0x7DA8FFB0          1364                2
6  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1365                3
7  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1365                3
...
```

Then, the [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and `lambda` function Gets the `min` and `max` times of the interaction, and renames it to `time_start` and `time_end`:

```
                 time_start  time_end
interaction_num                      
1                      1356      1363
2                      1364      1364
3                      1365      1366
4                      1366      1366
...
```

You then merge the result of that `groupby` with your original dataframe, where `interaction_num` matches the index, resulting in:

```
...
3  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1362                1        1356      1363
4  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1363                1        1356      1363
5  0x597E5627  0x7DA8FFB0          1364                2        1364      1364
6  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1365                3        1365      1366
7  0x597E5627  0x3C992634          1365                3        1365      1366
...
```

And finally you create a column of the time differences using `assign` again, and `groupby` `interaction_num` again, and dropping the unnecessary `'time_local_s'` column, getting your final dataframe.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much, especially the explanation that helps out a lot with learning!

Comment: You're welcome! If it covers what you need, feel free to hit the [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) button!

Comment: i do have another problem now, i have to merge interactions if they took place in a period of 20 seconds from each other (because then the conversation didn't really end ofcourse, maybe somebody just walked by and interupted the interaction for 1 second). i have solved the problem but i cannot combine this info with my original dataset. i have added my code above. in my code i have now lost the part with the names of the chips...

Answer (score 0):

Try using dataframe shift and groupby as below,

```
import pandas
df = pd.read_csv('timemerger.csv')
g = (df['tag_me'] != df.shift().fillna(method='bfill')['tag_me']).cumsum().
rename('group')
print(df.groupby(['tag_them','tag_me',g])['time_local_s'].agg(['min','max']).reset
_index().rename(columns={'min':'time_start','max':'time_end'}).drop('group',axis
=1))
```